# How to generate texture mapping images?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, mapping, textures

I want to put/wrap images to 3D objects. To keep things simple and fast, instead of using(and learning) a 3D library I want to use mapping images. Mapping images are used in such a way:

[image: mapping usage]

So you generate the mapping images once for each object and use the same mapping for all images you want to wrap.

My question is how can I generate such mapping images (given the 3D model)? Since I don't know about the terminology my searches failed me. Sorry if I am using the wrong jargon.

Below you can see a description of the workflow.
[image] 
I have the 3D model of the object and the input image, i want to generate mapping images that I can use to generate the textured image.

I don't even know where to start, any pointers are appreciated.

**More info**

My initial idea was to somehow wrap a identity mappings (see below) using an external program. I have generated horizontal and vertical gradient images in Photoshop just to see if mapping works using photoshop generated images. The result doesn't look good. I wasn't hopeful but it was worth a shot.

input
[image]

mappings (x and y), they just resize the image, they don't do anything fancy. 
[image]
[image]

result
[image]
as you can see there are lots of artifacts. Custom mapping images I have generated by warping the gradients even looks worse.

Here is some more information on mappings: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#distortion_maps

I am using OpenCV remap() function for mapping.

Comment: to downvoter: care to explain the reason of the downvote?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. :(

Comment: @karlphillip: I added a descriptive figure, I hope my goal is more clear now

Comment: Cool, I'll look into that later.

Comment: @nimcap the term you are looking for is UV mapping.

Comment: @mmgp: actually UV mapping is a mapping from 2D to 3D. What I am looking for is a mapping from 2D to 2D. The destination is a projection of a 3D object.

Comment: @nimcap does your monitor allow you to see 3d objects ? Mine only allows projections.

Comment: @mmgp: yes i know. what I am trying to achieve is doing this 2D to 2D mapping in one step, instead of 2D->3D->2D. UV mapping is half the term I am looking for.

Comment: Have you searched for "texture mapping"? Interesting question, good luck.

Comment: I had a similar problem (well remotely similar at least) I had to write an app that projects an image to a model by picking identical points in both image and model and to create its uvmap model. At the end my solution was pretty much a battered one. I chose to use the obj format, so i drew randomly (sorted actually by area) all triangle outlines on an image file, mapped then through the obj format and then drew on the desired image with a similar mapping technique. I had to use no custom libraries whatsoever thought. good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you right here, you want to do all of it in 2D ?

calling warpPerspective() for each of your cube surfaces will be much more successful, than using remap()

pseudocode outline:

```
// for each surface:
//  get the desired src and dst polygon
//  the src one is your texture-image, so that's:
     vector<Point> p_src(4), p_dst(4); 
     p_src[0] = Point(0,0); 
     p_src[1] = Point(0,src.rows-1); 
     p_src[2] = Point(src.cols-1,0);
     p_src[3] = Point(src.cols-1,src.rows-1);
// the dst poly is the one you want textured, a 3d->2d projection of the cube surface.
// sorry, you've got to do that on your own ;(
// let's say, you've come up with this for the cube - top:
     p_dst[0] = Point(15,15); 
     p_dst[1] = Point(44,19); 
     p_dst[2] = Point(56,30);
     p_dst[3] = Point(33,44);

// now you need the projection matrix to transform from one to another:
Mat proj = getPerspectiveTransform( p_src, p_dst );

// finally, you can warp your texture to the dst-polygon:
warpPerspective(src, dst, proj, dst.size());
```

if you can get hold of the 'Learning Opencv' book, it's described around p 170.

final word of warning, since youre complaining about artefacts, - yes, it'll all look pretty cheesy, 'real' 3d engines do a lot of work here, subpixel-uv mapping, filtering,
mipmapping, etc. if you want it to look nice, consider using the 'real' thing.

btw, there's nice opengl support built into opencv

Comment: The thing is I will be using arbitrary 3D models instead of cube, cube was just to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: oh, that stuff is done by artists in maya / blender or such, it's very unlikely, that you can automate that (abusing a 2d api even) consider using models, that already come with proper uv coords and a 3d api, like opengl. will be much less work, i promise !

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to render the 3D-models UV to a texture. It will be easier to learn to render 3D than to do things this way. Especially since there are a lot of weaknesses in your aproach. difficult to to lighting and problems til the depth-buffer will be abundant.

Assuming all your objects shul ever only be viewed from one angle, you need to render each of them to 3 textures:

UV-map
Normal-map
Depth-map (to correct the depth-buffer)

You will still have to do shading in order to draw these to look like your object, and I don't even know how to do the depth-buffer-thing, I just know it can be done.

So in order to avoid learning 3D, your will have to learn all the difficult parts of 3D-rendering. Does not seem the easier route...