# Automatically Mapping Image Texture to UV Maps For Custom Mesh?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-manipulation, texture-mapping, 3d-modelling

I am trying to apply texture to 3D clothing model using openCV. I have the UV maps of the clothing model and an image of the texture I want to apply which I prepared using grabcut(). How do I deform the texture image to match my UV mesh using OpenCV or any other automated method. I am providing the input Texture Image and also the UV mesh of the clothing. I am new to 3D modeling and OpenCV and I am facing issues with this please help me out.

Input Texture Image
[image: Input Texture Image]

UV mapped mesh of 3D model
[image: UV mapped mesh of 3D model]

Similar query at this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878467/how-to-generate-texture-mapping-images)

Comment: Please, display the pictures and remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Yes Sure  I made the changes.